# Checking if a word from file matches a random character string from EditText

Tags: java, android, string, file, android-edittext

How can I check if set of random characters from String of EditText matches a certain word from file?

For example:

EditText input: TINARSE
Can match word like NASTIER, STAINER.
Suppose a word in file is denoted by i.

I know how read strings from file just cant figure out how to match it with the random character input using IF statements.

**Note: Length of string should be same as length EditText**

---

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    anagram=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.inputtext);
    submit=(Button)findViewById(R.id.submit);
    viewall=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.list);
    viewall.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
    submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            String a =anagram.getText().toString();
            checkword("cswfifteen.txt",a);



        }
    });

}
private void checkword(String Filename,  String a) {

    StringBuilder builder = null;
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    ArrayList<String> words= new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        builder = new StringBuilder();
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                getAssets().open(Filename)

        ));


        String Line;
            while ((Line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                builder.append(Line).append("\n");

            }
            String[] dict = builder.toString().split("\n");


                for (String i : dict) {



                    char[] b = i.toString().toCharArray();
                    Arrays.sort(b);

                   char[] c=a.replace("?","").toCharArray();
                    Arrays.sort(c);
                    if (String.valueOf(b).contains(String.valueOf(c)) && b.length==a.length()){
                        words.add(i);}



            }

        Collections.sort(words);
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            for (String i : words)
            {

                result.append(i + "\n");
            }
            viewall.setText(result.toString());


    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            reader.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort the text from EditText and word i from the file. Compare these two strings.

```
String textFromEditText= "zxbc";
String wordFromFile="cxbz";
char a[] = textFromEditText.toCharArray();
char c[] = wordFromFile.toCharArray();
Arrays.sort(a);
Arrays.sort(c);
System.out.println(String.valueOf(a).equalsIgnoreCase(String.valueOf(c)));
```

Comment: but in this case there will only be one word probably that matches. what about the rest that may match the set of letters?

Comment: can be there be something that sees if the set of letters are in the particular string?

Comment: Are you saying set of letters as substring?

Comment: Possibly ill give an example again: suppose the user enters SATREID. So the file may contain words like ARIDEST etc. Words from file that matches the set of letters.

Comment: In that case, you can read words from a file, sort those and compare with text from Edit Text string.

Comment: Thanks it worked! :) next i want to figur out that if user enters something like RETINA?. Now ? Can be any lette4 from A to Z so how to manage that. I was thinking of removing the ? And then sorting it and the printing words matching the sorted item but have the orignal length.

Comment: Will a user enter special characters also?

Comment: Hey actually i figured it out, Shanshak's solutions helped me :) Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `String.contains()`.

```
String name="what do you know about me";
if(name.contains("do you know"))
{
// do stuff
}
```

You can use extra attributes in conjunction with `contains()` like, `trim()` and `equalsIgnoreCase()`.

Comment: Thanks shashank for the answer :) i tried pradip's way and it worked :)

Comment: Can you please upvote If you've found the solutions helpful in any aspect. Thank you. :)

Comment: hey shanshak, tell me one thing? does contains look for the order of a string? like shd the order be same? suppose a word is ARIDEST and i do SATIRE? where ? can be any letter from A-Z so will Contain match the other 6 letters if we exclude the ?

Comment: Thanks Alot Shankshak ur answer really helped :D. Sorry i can vote up but being a new user my vote cannot be displayed for now :) CHEERS! :)

Comment: I think yes. Using regex(regular expressions) it is posible. Try googling around for regex for letter-set of a word, you should get something useful. TLDR; It is doable.

Comment: @WaliMuhammadKhubaib , From your code, it seems `a.length = c.length`. so try using `String.valueOf(b).equals(String.valueOf(c))` instead of `String.valueOf(b).contains(String.valueOf(c)) && b.length==a.length()` and see if it works. All in all, glad i could help. Thanks. :)

Comment: To make it more concise, use `.trim()` from both the strings. That'll remove all the redundant spaces in you string. `String.valueOf(b).trim().equals(String.valueOf(c).trim())`

Comment: yes ur point is valid when it comes to exactly the same chracters but my intention as tht if user enters a ? so ? can be any character from A-Z so first i created a char array in which i have omitted ? which is c actually and b is the actual word sorted in char array. thats why ive matched the lengths. so now i want to figur out how can i counter the problem when it comes to words which do not contain the exactly sequence such as ?AEIRST. now in this if we omit ? we are left with AEIRST so this will work for all values after T but anything tht comes between in it will be omitted. how to avoid?

Comment: **?AEIRST. now in this if we omit ? we are left with AEIRST so this will work for all values after T but anything tht comes between in it will be omitted.** can you give a detailed example. It is not quite clear to me. And please mark my solution as accepted, if helped

Comment: see **?AEIRST** now here ? can be any letter from A-Z so here if we here a word sorted charArray that matches something like ABEIRST or ACEIRST is omitted and a word that may match AEIRSTU or AEIRSTW is displayed so i want so show all the possible words that are in the file that can match ?AEIRST like i said ? can be any letter from A-Z

Comment: @WaliMuhammadKhubaib You can use `String.valueOf(a).substring(1)` this will take every thing after the first character in a string(a word in your case). Mark it correct, if useful. Cheers :)

Comment: then where do i implement this?

Comment: and also there are possibilites that user may also enter ? twice to check more combinations

Comment: how to match everything else except ? or any other letter

Comment: This should be done in the `if` statement itself. Try googling its use case.

Comment: I understand what you're trying is to check the availability of a word in the input string starting from last letter of the input string. use `inputword.substring(inputword.length() - yourCheckingword.length` in your `if` condition.This will take care of the scenario **?AEIRST** or **????AEIRST** since now you're parsing from the last and not the start of the input word.

Comment: Can you elaborate further on how i can apply to the if statement :)

Comment: editted my question and have added my code, please guide how can i make changes to achieve what i want? :)

Answer (score 0):

```
for (String i : dict) {

                    char[] b = i.toString().toCharArray();
                    Arrays.sort(b);
                    char c[]=a.replace("?","").toCharArray();
                    Arrays.sort(c);
                    if (String.valueOf(b).contains(String.valueOf(c)) && b.length==a.length()) {
                        words.add(i);}


            }

        Collections.sort(words);
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            for (String i : words)
            {
                result.append(i + "\n");
            }
```

This is my code. it works good but is omitting some words that donot match the contains method. Example a sorted may be ?AEIRST where blank can be any letter from A to Z so it will ignore some words that after sorting their letters may contain a B or C or D on te 2nd index. how to counter that?